# What is the push Notification method for iOS 8?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios8

What is the new method for Push Notification in iOS 8?

I am using this method, but its not working.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Anybody can guide me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Silent” pushes are push notifications that don’t create UI; they instead tell your app to fetch or react to new content available online.

In iOS 8, Apple has separated out the permissions for UI and push. The push permission is auto-accepted by default too! This means your iOS 8 apps will be able to much more reliably depend on the ability to receive silent notifications in iOS 8.

To migrate your app, change the following code:

// Before iOS 8:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

// For iOS 8:

```
 UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```